# How to use startup command to start detached tmux session on azure app service

Tags: azure, tmux, azure-appservice

I'm trying to start a tmux session when my app service is deployed so i don't have to run it manually.

I'm using the following startup commands. They all run, except for the last one. Any idea, what could be the problem?

If I place it before I start gunicorn, my app services won't start. The logs do not give me any valuable insights what is the reason for the failure.

If i place it after gunicorn, the app service starts. But the tmux session is not created.

```
apt-get update && apt-get -y install tmux

#start django
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --workers=4 --timeout 600 app.wsgi

#additional commands
tmux new-session -d 'python manage.py monitor'
```

Comment: Instead of `monitor` try with `runserver` once.

Comment: monitor is the custom command it has the run. I'm aware of the runserver command, but that is not the custom command i want it to startup with

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to check whether `tmux` is installed in the `App Service` or not before starting a `tmux` session.

Open `SSH` .
`https://YourAppServiceName.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host`

- Run the below command to check the version of `tmux`.

```cs
tmux -V
```

`tmux` is not installed in the Azure Web App.

[image]

- In `SSH`, Install `tmux` with the below command.

```cs
 apt-get install tmux
```

[image]

[image]

Now, we can set the startup command in `Configuration` => `General Settings` section and `Save`.

```cs
tmux new-session -d 'python manage.py monitor'
```

[image]

- After updating the startup command, when I opened the SSH,I got the below error.

[image]

[image]

- I have removed the `startup command` and tried to create session in `SSH` manually, to check whether the command is working or not.

Tried with the below command.

```cs
tmux new-session
```

- Command to check the list of sessions.

```cs
tmux list-sessions
```

[image]

- Make sure the path to the manage.py is correct.

```
tmux new-session -d 'python manage.py monitor'
```

I have observed that, when we restart the App service, `tmux` is getting uninstalled.

Comment: so, did you get it working or not. Because if i read your comment, you are actually saying that tmux is uninstalled.

For the record. I'm able to get tmux installed on startup. That is not the problem. The problem is to get tmux new-session -d 'python manage.py monitor' run on startup. But somehow, it does not run.